# Dihedral group property proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, dihedral-groups

In Dummit and Foote , in section 1.2 Dihedral groups these are left as exercise.

> We leave the details of the following calculations as an exercise
>
> $(i)$ $1, r, r^2,...,r^{n-1}$ are all distinct and $r^{n} = 1$, so
> $|r|  = n$.
> $(ii)$ $|s|= 2$.
> $(iii)$ $s \neq r^i$ for any $i$.
> $(iv)$ $sr^i \neq sr^j$, for all $0 \leq i, j \leq n- 1$ with
> $i\neq j$, so i.e., each element can be written uniquely in the form $s^kr^i$
> for some $k = 0$ or  $1$ and $0 \leq i \leq n - 1$.

$(i)$ At first I want to show $r^n=1$ and $s^2=1$. But I couldn't.  Because  I know $r$ is the rotation about the origin $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Now after rotatating n times we rotate $n×\frac{2\pi}{n}=2\pi$ times. And we got $1$. So $r^n=1$ and similarly for refelction after rotatating 2 times we get the 1 so $s^2=1$.but this is intuitive. I can't find a way to show this mathematically, I think for that I need mathematical representation of $r$.

Once we can show $r^n=s^2=1$ then rest are very easy.for $(i)$ if $r^i=r^j$ then $r^{i-j}=1$ so $i-j \geq n$ but as $0 \leq i, j \leq n- 1$ so $i-j \leq n-1 \lt n$ so contradiction. And for $(iii)$ and for first part of $(iv)$ proceeding same as $(i)$ we can get contradiction.

But how to show the uniqueness part? What is the meaning of each element? Do we have to show all  the powers $r,s$ that is  $s^pr^q$, $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be written in the form $s^kr^i$, where $k,i$ is as defined in the question $(iv)$, but thats follows from $r^n=s^2=1$ so , its reduced to $s^{p \pmod{2}} r^{q \pmod{n}}$ , so if let $k=p \pmod{2}$ and $i=q \pmod{n}$ then we have desired result. But how to show its unique?

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is: if $sr^i=sr^j$ and $i<j$, then $r^{j-i}=1$; if $sr^i=r^j$, then $s=r^{j-i}$.

Comment: @kabenyuk yeah I think i have made mistake in numbering questions

Comment: @kabenyuk $(iii)$ If $s=r^i$ for some $i$ now $1=s^2=sr^i=r^ir^i=r^{2i}$ now $2i \geq n$ as $n$ is order of $r$ now $1=r^{2i-n}.r^n=r^{2i-n}$ now $0 \leq i \leq n-1 \implies 0 \leq 2i-n \leq n-1 \lt n$ so a contradiction $(iv)$ if $sr^i=sr^j$, multiply left side by $s$ so $r^i=r^j$ but this contradiction from $(i)$

Comment: Yes, I see that you have understood how to solve the uniqueness  question.

Comment: @kabenyuk how to show $r^n=1,s^2=1$?

Comment: I think your proof of (i) is not correct. You haven’t yet proved $r^i\neq 1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n-1$. So you can’t conclude $r^{i-j}=1$$\implies$$i-j\geq n$. To be honest, I also don’t understand uniqueness part.